# Segmentation fault during call to DPOSV routine from MKL 11.3 library

Tags: fortran, lapack, intel-fortran, intel-mkl

I am trying to run the following code, compiling with IFORT 2016, linking MKL 11.3 library:

```
program bug
  implicit none
  INCLUDE 'mkl.fi'
  integer*4, parameter :: Npart=25
  real(kind=8) :: u(1:Npart), lapackab(1:Npart,1:Npart)
  integer*4 :: i

  u=0.2d0
  lapackab=0d0
  do i=1,Npart
      lapackab(i,i)=2d0
  enddo

  call DPOSV('L',Npart,1,lapackab,Npart,u,Npart,i)
  write(*,*) "i=",i
end program
```

using the following command:

```
ifort -O0 -g -openmp -o file.o -c file.f90 -I/opt/share/INTEL/mkl/include
ifort -O0 -g -openmp file.o -o run -L/opt/share/INTEL/mkl/lib/  -I/opt/share/INTEL/mkl/include  -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

for some obscure reason, the code segfaults during the DPOSV.
I have no idea why. Seriously, even Valgrind does not report anything weird..
Is there anybody that had the same issue with this particular routine?

EDIT: the code works perfectly with LAPACK 3.6.1 but not with MKL 11.3. I sent a post on the Intel Support forum, but it still has to be approved by moderators..

Comment: I am *almost* sure that the arguments are correct. Both LAPACK and MKL user guides report that DPOSV requires 8 arguments. I may have made mistakes, but I checked the arguments many times..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are linking the [`ILP64`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-macos-developer-guide-using-the-ilp64-interface-vs-lp64-interface) version of MKL but that one is used for 64-bit integers. You are using `integer*4` so your integers are 32-bit (and the default integers as well). Use the [MKL link advisor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor) to link MKL correctly. You likely need the `LP64` version.

Comment: Thank you man, you made my day. I would have never noticed this thing ..